# Deserialize an enum in Rust with both unit and non-unit versions without writing a custom deserializer

Tags: json, rust, serde

```rust
use serde::{Deserialize, Serialize};

#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize, Debug)]
enum Animal {
    Cat(Option<String>),
    Dog(String),
    Bird,
}

fn main() {
    let json_animals = r#"
        [
            {"Cat": "Meow"},
            "Cat",
            {"Dog": "Bark"},
            "Bird"
        ]"#;
    println!("{:?}", serde_json::from_str::<Vec<Animal>>(json_animals).unwrap());
}
```

We basically need a way to deserialize both `"Cat"` and `{"Cat": "cat_name"}` into `Animal`. I know that writing a custom deserializer works but it will be better to have a cleaner solution.

I tried aliasing & renaming & options & defining `CatVariant` as a separate enum to include both cases. None of these works because of `Error("invalid type: unit variant, expected newtype variant", line: 5, column: 12)`

Comment: This sounds like a niche-enough use-case that I'll be surprised if you'll find a solution in `serde` or even popular libraries for it.

Comment: this look like bad json specification for sure

Comment: @Stargateur Yup it is pretty bad. However we still have to get this edge case parsed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this without a custom `Deserialize` implementation, but it will require creating a few extra types to handle the various alternatives present in your schema.

Since we can't directly make `Animal` implement `Deserialize` for your schema, we can create another type that represents that schema and then convert to `Animal`.  `#[serde(from = "OtherType")]` will allow us to tell serde "deserialize `OtherType` and then convert it to this type."

```
#[derive(Deserialize, Debug)]
#[serde(from = "AnimalRepr")]
enum Animal {
    Cat(Option<String>),
    Dog(String),
    Bird,
}
```

So what does `AnimalRepr` look like?  Well, it's either a map or a string.  We can used an untagged enum to represent that.

```
#[derive(Deserialize, Debug)]
#[serde(untagged)]
enum AnimalRepr {
    Animal(AnimalType),
    BareAnimalType(BareAnimalType),
}
```

So now `AnimalType` will handle the maps and `BareAnimalType` will handle the strings.

```
#[derive(Deserialize, Debug)]
enum BareAnimalType {
    Cat,
    Bird,
}

#[derive(Deserialize, Debug)]
enum AnimalType {
    Cat(String),
    Dog(String),
}
```

Now we just need a way to convert `AnimalRepr` to `Animal`.  We can break this conversion apart by having both `BareAnimalType` and `AnimalType` convertible to `Animal`, and delegating to that conversion when converting `AnimalRepr`.

```
impl From<BareAnimalType> for Animal {
    fn from(value: BareAnimalType) -> Self {
        match value {
            BareAnimalType::Cat => Self::Cat(None),
            BareAnimalType::Bird => Self::Bird,
        }
    }
}

impl From<AnimalType> for Animal {
    fn from(value: AnimalType) -> Self {
        match value {
            AnimalType::Cat(n) => Self::Cat(Some(n)),
            AnimalType::Dog(n) => Self::Dog(n),
        }
    }
}

impl From<AnimalRepr> for Animal {
    fn from(value: AnimalRepr) -> Self {
        match value {
            AnimalRepr::Animal(v) => v.into(),
            AnimalRepr::BareAnimalType(v) => v.into(),
        }
    }
}
```

Putting it all together, we get:

```
use serde::{Deserialize, Serialize};

#[derive(Deserialize, Debug)]
enum BareAnimalType {
    Cat,
    Bird,
}

impl From<BareAnimalType> for Animal {
    fn from(value: BareAnimalType) -> Self {
        match value {
            BareAnimalType::Cat => Self::Cat(None),
            BareAnimalType::Bird => Self::Bird,
        }
    }
}

#[derive(Deserialize, Debug)]
enum AnimalType {
    Cat(String),
    Dog(String),
}

impl From<AnimalType> for Animal {
    fn from(value: AnimalType) -> Self {
        match value {
            AnimalType::Cat(n) => Self::Cat(Some(n)),
            AnimalType::Dog(n) => Self::Dog(n),
        }
    }
}

#[derive(Deserialize, Debug)]
#[serde(untagged)]
enum AnimalRepr {
    Animal(AnimalType),
    BareAnimalType(BareAnimalType),
}

impl From<AnimalRepr> for Animal {
    fn from(value: AnimalRepr) -> Self {
        match value {
            AnimalRepr::Animal(v) => v.into(),
            AnimalRepr::BareAnimalType(v) => v.into(),
        }
    }
}

#[derive(Deserialize, Debug)]
#[serde(from = "AnimalRepr")]
enum Animal {
    Cat(Option<String>),
    Dog(String),
    Bird,
}

fn main() {
    let json_animals = r#"
        [
            {"Cat": "Meow"},
            "Cat",
            {"Dog": "Bark"},
            "Bird"
        ]"#;
    println!("{:?}", serde_json::from_str::<Vec<Animal>>(json_animals).unwrap());
}
```

Which outputs:

```
[Cat(Some("Meow")), Cat(None), Dog("Bark"), Bird]
```

([Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=4ba3a1b2472174dec4ff7c4f72ff8011))

Comment: I don't even what to know what serde generate for all of this haha

Comment: @Stargateur Honestly, probably not too different from what you'd have to write by hand, just spread out over a few implementations instead of one.